# can I make a vlookup find a certain word in a cell?

Tags: excel, vlookup

What I am trying to do is.

```
=VLOOKUP(C7,MODEL!A$4:B$9975,2,FALSE)
```

For Cell C7--- Jacket Blue Men's

What I want it to do is use a Symbol for Men's

So my original sheet has the products all listed...this goes to another list and I want to make Jacket Blue Men's--------   | Jacket Blue |  ♂ |

So Does Vlookup recognise (Men's) and will use the list to autofill another cell?

I tried true and it gave me a `NA#`

Thanks...this is the last step in a MASSIVE puzzle

**NEW QUESTION**

Can I only have one Vlookup command per sheet?

Also the current `=VLOOKUP(B397,Sheet2!C3:D5,2)`  IS returning a ♂  but the specific word in that cell is Women's

So I guess I need to figure out how it will differentuate between women's and Men's.  I have tried many formulas, and I get `NA#` or errors in the formulas.

Can anyone answer this or am I really stuck and have to add ♂ and ♀ and Ω  to all 10k entries?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? In your original Question you say that C7 = Jacket Blue Men's - what do you want that to match with in MODEL!A$4:A$9975? Just "Jacket Blue"?

Comment: I am trying to match Men's to the symbol ♂ in another cell. The problem I have is that it also picks up Women's and that is now the biggest issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you want "Men's" to always match with "♂" then try using SUBSTITUTE which will replace any instance of "Men's" in the lookup value with that symbol, i.e.

`=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(C7,"Men's","♂"),MODEL!A$4:B$9975,2,FALSE)`

...or do you need it to be | ♂ |....I'm not clear....but the principle is the same....

`=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(C7,"Men's","| ♂ |"),MODEL!A$4:B$9975,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks Barry, I just went back and took out the ,FALSE and it all worked right for me. I will also try yours and keep it on record.

Comment: OK Further question. it works on a different page...but not the page I want it too..canj I only have one Vlookup command per page?